# How change The icon and colors both in checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox

I make my checkbox looks different by drawable:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
    android:state_selected="true"
    />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
    android:state_selected="false"
    />
```

And in the checkbox on layout I set
android:button="@drawable/mix_checkbox"

And it's ok. But for now, how can I set the different colors to those icon's I set? I have to try some ways from here, but unsuccessfully. Help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#000000"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
</selector>
```

Comment: I have try this one too. The only possibility to change color of custom icon that i find is in separate style set tint. But it's colors all states of checkbox, there is no select effect